# What are the consequences of message ratings, protection and dissapearing messages.

Tags: dark-souls-3

Sometimes a message appears in-game: "Someone has rated your message" and this glance appears on your character. What are the benefits/downsides of someone approving or disapproving your written messages in the game?

There's also an option for protecting messages, how does this work, I noticed that some of my messages dissapeared from my written messages list for a certain amount of time. My guess is that protecting a message will stop them from dissapearing. Though this is just my guess, can anyone verify this?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Someone approving your message gives you a heal (as well as a warm fuzzy feeling).
When the message pops up, there's a glow about your character that reminds me of the glow you get when drinking, or the glow from life leech effects.
The approval might also refill an Estus Flask use, I'm not as sure about that.

I haven't gotten any disapproving votes yet, but nothing happened from disapprovals in previous games. I suspect that disapprovals on a message may stop it from showing up.

Sources: From experience.  Getting whacked, then seeing the "Someone has rated your message" notice and watching my health go up.

Comment: Thanks for the input, do you have any sources of this? So I can accept this as an answer. :)

Comment: Approval does not refill Estus Flask use, but you're right about the heal. Estus Flasks have chance of being refilled when killing red-eyed enemies.
Regarding disapproving my guess is that messages with too many downvotes will be removed from the game after a while.

Comment: Never knew about the red-eyed enemies, was wondering about them though. +1.

Comment: I am fairly sure a downvote also gets you a heal. The implication here is that if you spam messages everywhere you go, they should be either truly helpful or truly outrageous. Mediocre will get a shrug, good or entertaining will get you free health

Answer (score 1):

The more dissaprovals the less likely it will appear for someone else to see. There will always be a chance but in my experience once a message has about 8 or so bad ratings you might as well delete it because most people won't see it.